# Is it possible to be notified by Amazon Echo when it starts and stops speaking?

Tags: amazon-echo

i want to change audio source on my home cinema when Alexa is speaking so I need to be notified when it starts and stops.

somehow this seems like a more generic integration than a skill.

Comment: That's not possible with a skill. What other components are involved? Is a Pi or the like in the vicinity? You can also consider asking this on the IoT.SE (https://iot.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I cross posted it at https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/563/is-it-possible-to-be-notified-by-amazon-echo-when-it-starts-and-stops-speaking but my impression is that on SO this is more likely to get an answer. It is really annoying not to be able to use the audio system due to this.